# Java Having trouble saving file

Tags: java, file, save

I am trying to have my program save, but whenever I try to save a program that exists (so the second run through) it creates the temp, but it does not overwrite the old file.

Here is the code. Can anyone find out why it does not overwrite the old file with the new?

```
public static void saveBallotData(int i)throws IOException{

    PrintWriter outputFile;
    outputFile = new PrintWriter("temp2.txt");
    File tempCheck = new File (list.get(i).getBallotNumber()+".txt");
    if(tempCheck.exists()){
        Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(tempCheck);
        for(int m = 0; m < list.get(i).getNumberOfChoices(); m++){
            if(list.get(i).getVote().equals(list.get(i).getChoice(m))){
                //outputFile.println(list.get(i).getChoice(m) + ":" + getInt(m, tempCheck) + 1);
                inputFile.nextLine();
            }
            else{
                outputFile.println(inputFile.nextLine());
            }
        }
    }
    else{
        for(int a = 0; a < list.get(i).getNumberOfChoices(); a++){
            if(list.get(i).getVote().equals(list.get(i).getChoice(a))){
                outputFile.println(list.get(i).getChoice(a) + ":" + "1");
            }
            else{
                outputFile.println(list.get(i).getChoice(a) + ":" + "0");
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("PHE");
    outputFile.close();
    File g = new File("temp2.txt");
    File f = tempCheck;
    f.delete();
    g.renameTo(f);
}
```

Comment: If `tempCheck` exists the code is writing to `temp2.txt` not to the old file `tempCheck`. Do you want to overwrite `tempCheck`?

Comment: Yea. I want to overwrite tempCheck

Comment: @TonyRad Well, actually, I want to overwrite the file (list.get(i).getBallotNumber()+".txt");

Comment: Those last four lines are a rather confusing alternative to "tempCheck.delete(); outputFile.renameTo(tempCheck);"

Comment: @ChristopherMartin You can't do outputFile.renameTo(tempCheck);

Comment: Sorry, misread that, thought outputFile was a File. I'm going to blame you for the misleading variable name ;)